# Laravel Category, subCategory and Post

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a 1 category and subcategory table 
[table name: categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9NrR.png)

[image]

another table is posts [posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8j9g.png)

[image]

when click on google app script all post regarding category and sub category of google app script will show [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUHDu.png)

[image]

my controller code is and name of controller is bloglistController

```
$posts = post::where('category_id', $id)->paginate(7);
```

but this code shows only category id post I want post of both category and sub category

Comment: plz check the links for table structure

Comment: try something like Category::where(parent_id, 1)->with('post')

Comment: nah it doesn't help

Comment: my code is incomplete u need to go through laravel eager laoding

Comment: define hasMany relation for parent_id in category model to post model category_id field

Comment: can u share a code

Answer (score 0):

For category model

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'parent_id', 'category_id');
}
```

In your controller

```
$category = Category::where('parent_id',1)->first();
$post = $category->post;
```

Comment: I think it works, but I got some error. 
I want all the data so, I used to get(); instead of first();
I used like this : 
foreach ($category->post as $new) {
             echo $new->title;
        }
but I got error Property [post] does not exist on this collection instance.